# android - settext on responsehandler throws error

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread that's posting to a rails server. I've created a response handler for it that sets the UI to the result of that post, however I'm getting a called from wrong thread exception. If I'm not supposed to update my UI in my response handler, how else can I do it?

Here's my thread

```
Thread translateText = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost post=new HttpPost("[my url]");


            List<NameValuePair> form=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "test"));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, HTTP.UTF_8));

            String responseBody=client.execute(post, finishTranslation);

        }
        catch(Exception t){
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

And here's my response handler

```
ResponseHandler<String> finishTranslation = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
    public String handleResponse(
            HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {

            String res = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            System.out.println(res);

            tv_Translation.setText(res); // error gets thrown here

            return res;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with ResponseHandler, but it looks like this is used on a non-UI thread for additional processing, and it can return any object you create in the context of the handleReponse method BACK to the UI thread.

So, since you're calling client.execute on a background thread in the first place, you'll still need to "post" back to the UI thread with Handler.post(Runnable)